# Read only and write only automatic properties in Interface

Tags: c#, properties, interface

I had read that auto implemented properties cannot be read only or write only. They can only be read-write.

However, while learning interfaces I came across foll. code, which creates a read only / write only and read-write type of automatic properties. Is that acceptable?

```
 public interface IPointy 
    {   
    // A read-write property in an interface would look like: 
    // retType PropName { get; set; }   
    //  while a write-only property in an interface would be:   
    // retType PropName { set; }  
      byte Points { get; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not auto-implemented. Interfaces do not contain implementation.

It's a declaration that the interface `IPointy` requires *a property of type `byte`, named `Points`, with a public getter*.

---

You can implement the interface in any way necessary as long as there is a public getter; whether by an auto-property:

```
public class Foo: IPointy
{
    public byte Points {get; set;}
}
```

Note the setter can still be private:

```
public class Bar: IPointy
{
    public byte Points {get; private set;}
}
```

Or, you can explicitly write a getter:

```
public class Baz: IPointy
{
    private byte _points;

    public byte Points
    {
        get { return _points; }
    }
}
```