# Explicit implementation of an interface using a getter-only auto-property (C# 6 feature)

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Using automatic properties for explicit interface implementation [was not possible in C# 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905035/1565070), but now that C# 6 supports [getter-only auto-properties](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/getter-only-auto-properties-in-C-Sharp-6-0/), this should be possible now, right?

Creating the auto-property succeeds in C# 6, but when trying to assign a value to it in the constructor, you have to cast `this` to the interface type first, since the implementation is explicit. But that's where both VS 2015 RC and VS Code 0.3.0 display the error that can be seen in the comment:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public interface IFoo { string TestFoo { get; } }

    public class Impl : IFoo
    {
        // This was not possible before, but now works.
        string IFoo.TestFoo { get; }

        public Impl(string value)
        {
            // ERROR: Property or indexer 'IFoo.TestFoo' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.
            ((IFoo)this).TestFoo = value;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        // Yes, not static. DNX supports that (for constructor DI).
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IFoo foo = new Impl("World");

            WriteLine($"Hello {foo.TestFoo}");
            ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: I updated the original question that set a constant value to `TestFoo`. In my real-world scenario, the value comes from an object that is injected into the constructor. The [answer by Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30672805/1565070) is excellent if the value returned by the property can be set at initialization.**

It says:

> Property or indexer 'IFoo.TestFoo' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Is there a way around this, or do I still have to use properties with backing fields for this case?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 RC and Visual Studio Code 0.3.0 with DNX451 1.0.0-beta4.

**I have [raised an issue over at the Roslyn GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3342).**

---

The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022654/read-only-and-write-only-automatic-properties-in-interface) is a question about the definition of an interface with a regular property that can be read. My question is about implementing such an interface explicitly using a new C# 6 feature, that, in theory, should make this possible. See the other question I linked in the first sentence for a similar one (but for C# 5, where getter-only auto-properties where not available yet).

Comment: i'm guessing its just a bug or the compiler can't figure out that its settable because its behind the interface which is only readonly.

Comment: @DanielA.White It's not much different than a normal property. `string Foo { get; }` is legal now although in that case you could set it in the constructor.

Comment: @DanielA.White, yes. I guess the compiler only allows direct accesses to the property from the constructor and the casting is not allowed.

Comment: @mikez theres a cast involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read only and write only automatic properties in Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022654/read-only-and-write-only-automatic-properties-in-interface)

Comment: @Powerlord, the person in the linked question was confused about an interface definition (he/she thought it was a getter-only property definition). My question is about whether a new C# 6 feature can be used to explicitly implement an interface.

Comment: [dotnet/csharplang#1219](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1219)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around this by using a read-only backing field for your explicitly implemented property. You can assign the injected value to the backing field within the constructor, the explicit property's get implementation will return it.

```
public class Impl : IFoo
{
    private readonly string _testFoo;

    string IFoo.TestFoo => _testFoo;

    public Impl(string value)
    {
        _testFoo = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this

```
string IFoo.TestFoo { get; } = "World";
```

Comment: Probably better guess than my `string IFoo.TestFoo { get; private set; }` thought ;p

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: The value that is given to `TestFoo` comes from an object injected into the constructor, but thank you.

Comment: @NikontheThird: Does my suggestion work? I dont think it will, but it could be a nice 'syntactic solution' to express the intent. Might be worthwhile logging an issue on roslyn github.

Comment: @leppie, [sadly, no](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905035/1565070), since this syntax would have already been possible in C# 5. But the compiler doesn't like the `private set` part.

Comment: @leppie An explicit implementation of any member is not allowed to declare access modifiers.

Comment: @NikontheThird: Yeah, I just checked it out too. My suggestion is not really good either...

Comment: Upvoted because, although not an answer to the question, it does show a use case where an explicit automatic property is not completely useless.