# Assign a value to an explicitly-implemented readonly interface property in a constructor

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

Same question [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672761/explicit-implementation-of-an-interface-using-a-getter-only-auto-property-c-6), but for C# 7.0 instead of 6.0:

Is there a way to assign a value to an explicitly-implemented read-only (getter only) interface property in a constructor?  Or is it still the same answer, i.e. use the backing-field work-around?

For example:

```
interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

class MyPerson : IPerson
{
    string IPerson.Name { get; }

    internal MyPerson(string withName)
    {
        // doesn't work; Property or indexer 'IPerson.Name' 
        // cannot be assigned to --it is read only
        ((IPerson)this).Name = withName; 
    }
}
```

Work-around:

```
class MyPerson : IPerson
{
    string _name;
    string IPerson.Name { get { return _name; } }

    internal MyPerson(string withName)
    {
        _name = withName; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think you could just implement the property as `string IPerson.Name { get; private set; }` EDIT: After testing, turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: @itsme86 unfortunately no you can't with an explicit interface implementation - `IPerson.Name`.  If he didn't use the explicit reference to `IPerson` he could, but there are times you need the explicit call due to duplicate/conflicting names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of C# 7, the best you can do is to take advantage of expression-bodied properties and constructors to slightly simplify your code:

```
class MyPerson : IPerson
{
    string _name;
    string IPerson.Name => _name;

    internal MyPerson(string withName) => _name = withName;
}
```

This doesn't directly address your question though: having a means of setting an interface-explicit property from the constructor. There is a proposal though that *might* address this in the future, but there are no guarantees.

[Proposal: Property-Scoped Fields](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/133), which suggests allowing the contextual keyword `field` to be used within properties to refer to the backing field, without having to explicitly define the latter. It's possible that this might also provide syntax along the lines of:

```
string IPerson.Name { get; }
internal MyPerson(string withName) => IPerson.Name.field = withName;
```

However, the above link is to just a discussion topic on the C# language repo on GitHub. I hasn't (yet) been "championed" by the language team, which is the first step to it even being considered as a new feature. so the odds are this will never be added to the language (but things defy the odds sometimes, so never say never...)

Comment: Is there any document or discussion explaining why C# compiler does not allow read-only auto property in constructor when that property is explicitly implemented?

Answer (score 0):

No you still would require the same workaround in C# 7.  If you were referring to expression bodied members being extended to the constructor, it does not have any effect that lifted this restriction.