# Access interface member value defined with interface name ( IDo.Data {get} )

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Im new to c# and I dont know how to access the KeyboardHeightChanged member.

Code:

```
public interface IKeyboardInteractionService
    {
        public Subject<float> KeyboardHeightChanged { get; }
    }
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public partial class DetailsViewModel : IKeyboardInteractionService
    {

        Subject<float> IKeyboardInteractionService.KeyboardHeightChanged { get; }
}
```

The thing I'm trying to do is to get the KeyboardHeightChanged value in the second class, where inheritance is performed.

Comment: In which "second class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IKeyboardInteractionService` is an interface, not a class. It defines set of properties/methods which must be implemented in every class implementing it.
Your `DetailsViewModel` should look like this :

```
public partial class DetailsViewModel : IKeyboardInteractionService
{

    public Subject<float> KeyboardHeightChanged { get; } 

    ... rest of code
}
```

Comment: There was *absolutely nothing wrong* with the code shown in the question. Explicit interface implementation is perfectly acceptable and does not have to be replaced with implicit implementation as this answer implies. The question was about accessing the property and not defining it...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, There might be a bit wrong with it. An explicit interface implementation written as an auto-property (i.e. autogenerated getter body, and autogenerated backing field) where there is no `set` accessor, and no initialization of a value directly at the property declaration (as in `X I.P { get; } = new X();`) makes it impossible to initialize the backing field in an instance constructor. See the thread [Explicit implementation of an interface using a getter-only auto-property (C# 6 feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672761/).

Comment: Of course there are many ways to fix this while maintaining the explicit interface implementation.

Comment: @LiorV you can't... Why do you think they could do explicit implementation with `public`????